# install php-xml on centos 7

Tags: php, xml, centos7

trying to install php-xml on centos7 (php 5.6)

getting following error

```
[root@server ~]# sudo yum install php-xml
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * atomic: www4.atomicorp.com
 * epel: epel.mirror.constant.com
 * remi-safe: remi.mirror.ate.info
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:5.4.45-56.el7.art will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-56.el7.art for package: php-xml-5.4.45-56.el7.art.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-xml-5.4.45-56.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-56.el7.art
           Installed: php-common-5.6.33-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.33-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-42.el7
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.el7_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.el7_4
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-54.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-54.el7.art
           Available: php-common-5.4.45-56.el7.art.x86_64 (atomic)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.45-56.el7.art
          ...
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I've read around and people are suggesting i downgrade my php, however, i need 5.6 for scripts im trying to run.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As the error says the `php-xml` lib has the `php-common` lib as dependency which is installed, but the problem is that the `php-common` version installed is newer than the version required by `php-xml`. One solution is trying to downgrade `php-common`

Comment: You probably need to do a little research on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ Not really a good fit for SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>       Installed: php-common-5.6.33-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
> ```

As you have php 5.6 from **remi-php56** repository you have to enable the same repository to install additional extensions.

As explained by the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) :

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
yum install php-xml
```

P.S. and you should disable atomic and webtatic, as you don't use PHP from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading the `php-common` lib by running the following command: ([More info](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6087))

```
sudo yum downgrade php php-common php-cli
```

Comment: Thanks @claudio, see errors; https://pastebin.com/xYpJpt8T.