# Problems install install zend opcache

Tags: php, centos, centos6, pecl, opcache

**I have problem for install zendopcache**

```
  [root@cp ~]# yum install php-pecl-zendopcache
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
    Setting up Install Process
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
    Excluding mirror: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
    Excluding mirror: mirror.nl.leaseweb.net
     * epel: mirror.23media.de
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package php-pecl-zendopcache.x86_64 0:7.0.5-2.el6 will be installed
    --> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-zendopcache-7.0.5-2.el6.x86_64
    --> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-pecl-zendopcache-7.0.5-2.el6.x86_64
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution
    Error: Package: php-pecl-zendopcache-7.0.5-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
               Installed: php-common-5.6.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(zend-abi) = 20090626
    Error: Package: php-pecl-zendopcache-7.0.5-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
               Requires: php(api) = 20090626
               Installed: php-common-5.6.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
                   php(api) = 20131106-64
               Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
                   php(api) = 20090626
     You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
     You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
    [root@cp ~]#
```

I try many times and i try all and i don´t know what i can do for fix this, thanks for the help

Actually in server use Centos 6 64 bits, and run php 5.6

Comment: "I have a problem" We all do. Explain what your code is supposed to do in an [edit] and explain where your problem is.

Comment: What code , do you know about servers or what, you see it´s no code it´s response from server when install one module in centos what are you say, if you don´t know nothing about this for what say these things what code, this it´s for servers and if you havent any idea the best don´t speak

Answer (score 0):

try this, maybe it could help,

```
sudo wget http://packages.psychotic.ninja/7/base/x86_64/RPMS//keychecker-0.2-8.el7.psychotic.noarch.rpm 
yum install keychecker-1.0-3.el7.noarch.rpm
keychecker
yum remove remi-release
wget http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-7.rpm
vi /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
enabled=1 `line 30`
yum update
yum install php
yum install php-opcache
```

Comment: nothing continue problem  Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-pecl-zendopcache-7.0.5-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.6.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
               php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-49.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626

Answer (score 0):

Same question, same issue, same answer than  [install php-xml on centos 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100652/install-php-xml-on-centos-7/48101136#48101136)

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
yum install php-opcache
```